# jQuery DOM change requires JS to be run again, JS is an IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the JavaScript snippet below from a theme.

```
(function(namespace, $) {
    "use strict";

    var AppForm = function() {
        // Create reference to this instance
        var o = this;
        // Initialize app when document is ready
        $(document).ready(function() {
            o.initialize();
        });

    };
    var p = AppForm.prototype;

    // =========================================================================
    // INIT
    // =========================================================================

    p.initialize = function() {
        // Init events
        this._enableEvents();

        this._initRadioAndCheckbox();
        this._initFloatingLabels();
        this._initValidation();
    };

    // =========================================================================
    // EVENTS
    // =========================================================================

    // events
    p._enableEvents = function () {
        var o = this;

        // Link submit function
        $('[data-submit="form"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formId = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
            $(formId).submit();
        });

        // Init textarea autosize
        $('textarea.autosize').on('focus', function () {
            $(this).autosize({append: ''});
        });
    };

    // =========================================================================
    // RADIO AND CHECKBOX LISTENERS
    // =========================================================================

    p._initRadioAndCheckbox = function () {
        // Add a span class the styled checkboxes and radio buttons for correct styling
        $('.checkbox-styled input, .radio-styled input').each(function () {
            if ($(this).next('span').length === 0) {
                $(this).after('<span></span>');
            }
        });
    };

    // =========================================================================
    // FLOATING LABELS
    // =========================================================================

    p._initFloatingLabels = function () {
        var o = this;

        $('.floating-label .form-control').on('keyup change', function (e) {
            var input = $(e.currentTarget);

            if ($.trim(input.val()) !== '') {
                input.addClass('dirty').removeClass('static');
            } else {
                input.removeClass('dirty').removeClass('static');
            }
        });

        $('.floating-label .form-control').each(function () {
            var input = $(this);

            if ($.trim(input.val()) !== '') {
                input.addClass('static').addClass('dirty');
            }
        });

        $('.form-horizontal .form-control').each(function () {
            $(this).after('<div class="form-control-line"></div>');
        });
    };

    // =========================================================================
    // VALIDATION
    // =========================================================================

    p._initValidation = function () {
        if (!$.isFunction($.fn.validate)) {
            return;
        }
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                }
                else if (element.parent('label').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });

        $('.form-validate').each(function () {
            var validator = $(this).validate();
            $(this).data('validator', validator);
        });
    };

    // =========================================================================
    // DEFINE NAMESPACE
    // =========================================================================

    window.materialadmin.AppForm = new AppForm;
}(this.materialadmin, jQuery)); // pass in (namespace, jQuery):
```

This JavaScript does some UI stuff.

I've also written some jQuery/JS of my own for my application.  This jQuery adds and removes HTML from the DOM.

I have a form and two buttons, one being add and one being remove.  When the used clicks add/remove it duplicates or removes one of the forms.

After doing so, the effects from the JS above are no longer applied.  How can I reapply this every time the DOM is changed?

Comment: There is no indication of how the content is being removed or added. That would probably be a good start to making this question answerable.

Comment: you want to use delegate

Comment: It's like so: $(document).on('click', '.my_button_here', function() { //add content });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an instance of the `AppForm` function attached to the window object:

```
window.materialadmin.AppForm = new AppForm;
```

So can you simply call:

```
materialadmin.AppForm.initialize();
```

After you've done your DOM manipulation?

If not, then you're going to need to alter `AppForm` so that it is applied to future elements (not just the elements it finds in the DOM during initialization). Or provide a wrapper and/or public method that gives you access to the `AppForm` functionality that's needed after your DOM changes.

**Update**

Instead of calling `initialize()` again and binding additional click events, why not change the click events so that they fire on future elements? So instead of:

```
$('[data-submit="form"]').on('click', function (e) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Try:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-submit="form"]', function (e) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: the `$('xxx').on` will add a listener on elements that already exists too

Comment: In addition to this, you could also just call the sub-init methods if you only need to do one or the other. `materialadmin.AppForm._initFloatingLabels();`. Of course, this won't solve the issue of the methods possibly attaching multiple event handlers.

Comment: That did it, thanks.